# Exporting output to Notepad

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

i am trying create a file in Python 2.6.6. Its working in Python 2.7

```
fp = open('command_file.txt', 'w')
fp.write(device1 + '#' + intstatus + '\n' + device1 + '#\n')
```

command_file.txt is not being created when i run in Python 2.6.6 .

Any Idea how to fix it up ?

Comment: The file is almost certainly being created - but perhaps it's being created in a different directory than where you're looking?

Comment: i am login to root ...i dont see the file...

Comment: i tried 10:57:03 # find . -name command_file.txt...dont see the file..

Answer (score 1):

Are 'device1' and 'intstatus' strings? and also you might find it noteworthy to close the file

```
fp.write(string(device1) + '#' + string(intstatus) + '\n' + string(device1) + '#\n')
fp.close()
```

Comment: i dont see the file ...dont know either its being created and if yes then where is that ?

Comment: check the folder where the python script is present